# Referencing cells from a different worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

Im trying to reference data within a cell of first work sheet (active) on a second worksheet (trucks). When I use `=active!$L$34` on my second worksheet (trucks) it bring the right number over. However if I go back to "active" worksheet and use the "cut" and "paste" on cell L34 to move it somewhere else and replace the data in that cell in the same manner with data from a different cell, when I go back to "trucks" and go to cell A1 which is where I used `=ACTIVE!$L$34` the value is the same and the formula has changed to `=ACTIVE!$B$26` (which is where I copy/pasted the original data to) is there any way to make it so that the formula doesn't change (`=ACTIVE!$L$34` stays `=ACTIVE!$L$34` regardless of where I put the data in that cell?)

So what I'm trying to do is this.

Worksheet active is manually populated with vehicle ID number(2234) and its assignment(2A26). The Assignment value 2A26 never changes, however the vehicle ID number can change frequently. The work sheet is broken up in to 3 categories: in service, out of service, special use. The vehicle numbers will move all around the worksheet typically using the keyboard shortcut (Ctrl+X) and then placed in its appropriate spot with (Ctrl+V)

```
Worksheet ACTIVE
UNIT    TIME    STN     EHS #
A1  0600/1600   TER     2925
A2  0500/1700   SPR     2740
A3  0600/1600   GNA     2727
A4  0600/1600   PYL      
A5  0630/1830   BON     2103  ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀  ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀ ⠀  

Worksheet TRUCK
IN SERVICE      Out Of Service      Special service
EHS#    Asmnt       EHS#            EHS#    Asmnt
2727      A3        2234            2256     2P2
2740      A2                        
2925      A1
```

For Worksheet trucks is broken with the same 3 categories as active.
the difference with this worksheet is that I want to use the sort function to  rearrange the 3 categories in to numerical order based off the EHS#. However I need the EHS# and Asmnt info to come from EHS# and UNIT on worksheet active. Once this is done I want worksheet TRUCK to update and resort as changes are made to worksheet ACTIVE

```
Worksheet ACTIVE
UNIT    TIME    STN     EHS #
A1  0600/1600   TER     2924
A2  0500/1700   SPR     2918
A3  0600/1600   GNA     2782    

Worksheet Truck
IN SERVICE      Out Of Service      Special service
EHS#    Asmnt       EHS#            EHS#    Asmnt
2918     2A2        2234            2256    2P2
2924     2A1        2925
```

Hope the above helps a little.

Currently I'm using Excel 2007 for the most part. Some computers this will be run on will be running Excel 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
=INDIRECT("ACTIVE!L34")
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! It worked thanks!

Dont suppose you would be able to help me out with an auto sort code??

Now that I have the truck numbers coming across Im trying to sort them on to the new worksheet.
Sample of what Im trying to do is below.

ROAD TRUCKS

EHS #   Assignment
2740    A1
0   A2
2727    A3
0   A4
2103    A5
0   A6
2924    A7
2918    A8
2782    A9
2919    A10
0   A11
2793    A12
2386    A13
2929    A14
2894    A15
2250    A16
0   A17

As the EHS# changes in the "ACTIVE" worksheet it now updates it properly in the "truck" worksheet. Now Im trying to figure out how to update the sort function when there are changes made to the "truck" worksheet when the changes are made in the "ACTIVE" worksheet.

Thanks again!